# Google billing Library - Fragment getting disappeared after subscription purchase

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragments, play-billing-library

I am new to the implementation of Google's Billing library and using this system to make subscriptions inside my app. I have created a fragment that displays a list of subscriptions available for our product.

I have selected a test subscription from the list and purchased it. After a successful purchase of the subscription through Google Play billing library process, the fragment is getting closed immediately. I have also used setRetainInstance(true) in OnCreateView() method for the fragment to stay after the purchase but it doesn't work.

Can you please suggest on how to make my fragment **NOT TO DISAPPEAR** after the purchase is completed?